# Is there a way to specify a jupyter lab extension in a conda env?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to specify a jupyter labextension (for example, @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager) as a dependency for a project managed via conda with an environment.yml file? Or, is there a workaround to ensure everyone on my team can run notebooks which rely on lab extensions out-of-the-box?

Comment: Here is a link: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html#user-extensions -- I will wait and see the answer.

Comment: I see nothing about sharing environments on that page @swatchai?

Comment: It implicitely tells us that the matter is not simple but not impossible.

Comment: You will need to write a script that build-up an environment you want and let your co-workers run it once.

Comment: It does not work for Jupyter Lab, but [this](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) seems to be a way to have a large number of curated (though not customizable) Jupyter notebook extensions active in a conda environment by adding jupyter_contrib_nbextensions to the .yml file.

Comment: Cross-referencing with this issue I opened on the Jupyter GitHub: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10277

Answer (score 0):

... since I just had a similar problem and there seems to be no straight-forward way of doing this directly via the yml-files ... here's how I solved it
(using miniconda on Windows)

1. create an ordinary conda yml-file  `my_env.yml`
2. create a .bat file that runs the necessary commands `create_my_env.bat`

the .bat-file looks something like this:

```vb
REM activate conda base environment
set root=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
REM create environment
call conda env create -f my_env.yml
REM activate environment
call activate my_env
REM run additional commands
call jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
call jupyter lab build
    
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as raphael, but in a .sh file for Ubuntu. Typically my projects have a setup script that initializes the virtual environment anyways, so I just add "jupyter labextension install" commands after that. I'd love to see these extensions included in yml files, somehow, some day. But I expect that will never be possible, labextensions are quite different from python packages, in my understanding.

```
conda env create -f environment.yml    # this line installs jupyter lab
conda activate env_name

jupyter labextension install @axlair/jupyterlab_vim
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/git
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_conda
jupyter labextension install jupyter_conda
jupyter lab build
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is addressed using [prebuilt](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html#overview-of-extensions) extensions in JupyterLab 3.0+

From the docs:

> Because prebuilt extensions do not require a JupyterLab rebuild, they have a distinct advantage in multiuser systems where JuptyerLab is installed at the system level. On such systems, only the system administrator has permissions to rebuild JupyterLab and install source extensions. Since prebuilt extensions can be installed at the per-user level, the per-environment level, or the system level, each user can have their own separate set of prebuilt extensions that are loaded dynamically in their browser on top of the system-wide JupyterLab.

Example usage with the [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) and [jupyterlab-git](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git) extensions:

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge python jupyterlab jupytext jupyterlab-git
conda deactivate
conda env export -n myenv -c conda-forge --from-history > environment.yml 
conda activate myenv
jupyter lab
```

In the Jupyter Lab tab that's opened, the jupytext and jupyterlab-git extensions should be active. This should also be the case for environments later built from the `environment.yml` file.